# Spark Serialization, using class or object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I need some education for class, object with Serialization

Say, I have a spark main job, which maps a dataframe to another dataframe:

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
      val ss = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("test")
      .getOrCreate()

      val mydf = ss.read("myfile")

      // if call from object
      val newdf = mydf.map(x=>Myobj.myfunc(x)) 

      //if call from class
      val myclass = new Myclass()
      val newdf = mydf.map(x=>myclass.myfunc(x))
}

object Myobj {

   def myfunc(x:Int):Int = {
      x + 1
   }
}

class Myclass{

   def myfunc(x:Int):Int = {
      x + 1
   }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Which closure should I use to define `myfunc` within? an object or a class? What is the difference in terms of performance.
2. Should I `extends Serializable` for the object or class. Why?
3. I want to print/log some message from the object/class, what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: 3. Add print statements,  find out... 2. Doesn't hurt anything. 1. For this simple example, there's not much difference

Comment: I tried to add print statement, but it seems nothing come out..?

Comment: Besides, when must I extends Serializable for my class/object?

Comment: The print statement runs in the executor. You didn't specify how you run the code. But the logs can be seen in the Spark UI. In my experience, I only extend Serializable when I run into a serialization error.